# Problems with dispose();

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

In my program when a button is clicked the JFrame I'm using should close. However the `dispose()` method doesn't seems to work. Could anyone help me?

```
public class SetUp extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Checker {
    JFrame frame= new JFrame("Set Up");

    public mmSetUp() {      
        setSize(500, 300);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        

        setVisible(true);
        pack();

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == Submit) {
            windowclose();          
        }
    }

    public void windowclose() {

        frame.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

Well after checking your code it's **probably** because of your class extends `JFrame` and you're adding all your elements to this extended frame.

But you also create a `JFrame`, this isn't a good practice, 1st of all see [The use of multiple JFrames, Good / Bad Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) about using multiple frames.

Now going back into your code, let's see about it, as I said before, you're extending a `JFrame` on your class like this (I'll refer to this frame as **frame1**)

```
public class SetUp extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Checker {
```

But you also create a `JFrame` here (I'll refer to this frame **frame2**):

```
JFrame frame= new JFrame("Set Up");
```

You are trying to `dispose` the **frame2**, it's actually happening that, but if you want to dispose **frame1** (which is the one which has all your elements, i.e. the one you're working with), then on this method, you should change:

```
public void windowclose() {
    frame.dispose();
}
```

for this one:

```
public void windowclose() {

    this.dispose();
}
```

Also I don't recommend you to extend from `JFrame` class it's better to create objects from it like you did.

But if you do so, then you should change your code as follows:

```
public mmSetUp() {  

    frame.setSize(500, 300);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == Submit) {
        windowclose();          
    }
}

public void windowclose() {

    frame.dispose();
}
```

I'm not 100% sure this works or compiles, since I'm not at my PC atm, so I can't create a full example, but at 1st view that's what is happening on your class. In 3 more hours or so, I can post a compilable example.

But please check it

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 JFrames.
One, that is being extended.
Two, the one called *frame*.

First of all, you have only made one mistake.

Change windowclose() to:

```
public void windowclose() {
    dispose(); // Removed frame part
}
```

What you have done is, completely set up the extended JFrame from the start and left *frame* alone so its idle.

When windowclose() is called, it disposes the idle *frame* which essentially is useless as you have not even modified anything except for the title.

After you have changed windowclose() the code should work, now you can get rid of

```
JFrame frame= new JFrame("Set Up");
```

But if you want to keep everything neater, do as Frakcool said and remove *extends JFrame*

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to call `frame.setVisible( false )` instead.

Edit: your program has several logic errors.  Try this version instead:

```
  public class WindowCloseTest
  {
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
        new SetUp().mmSetUp();
     }
  }
  class SetUp implements ActionListener {
      JFrame frame= new JFrame("Set Up");

      public void mmSetUp() {      
          frame.setSize(500, 300);

          JButton b = new JButton( "Submit");
          b.addActionListener(this);
          frame.add( b, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
      }

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println( e );
          if (e.getActionCommand() == "Submit") {
              windowclose();          
          }
      }

      public void windowclose() {

          frame.dispose();
      }

  }
```

Comment: that doesn't work either :(

Comment: Are you calling it before you dispose the JFrame or after?

Comment: i tried both and neither worked

Comment: Well, you have several other errors in your code.  Mostly just logic errors.  I'll get a working program similar to yours posted in a sec.

Comment: the errors may be there as i missed out a lot of code when i copied it in to here, but thanks

Comment: Compare strings with `.equals()` not `==`.

Comment: Fair, but the Java spec says all program constant strings that are the same are the same object, so for this example I'm safe.  (In other words, it works, I tried it.)

Comment: comparing this to my original code i cannot see any differences and it still hasn't solved it

Comment: Well, cut and paste the code and diff it, I made several lines worth of changes.

Comment: i have done and it doesnt seem to make any difference, the program calls the windowclosed method but it doesnt work from there

Comment: Obviously then your program has problems that you haven't shown us, because my example works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @user2338547, there are some code you didn't show us that might cause the problem, I code my version of the use for dispose method, hope it can give you some idea of how to use the method

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class GuiTest extends JFrame{

        static GuiTest frame=new GuiTest("test");
        private JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        private JButton button=new JButton("close");
        private Button buttonListener=new Button();

        public GuiTest(String title){
            super(title);
            add(panel);
            panel.add(button);
            button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            frame.setSize(100,100);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        class Button implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            frame.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```